# mysql query for a contest vote finding duplicates every day

Tags: mysql, database

I have a vote table in mysql db.
vote id, vote pic, user id, vote ip, vote date, vote sum - like below.

It's not allowed to vote a picture from the same ip within every 24h and from other user_id (using same IP).

So I'm looking for a mysql query that will let me separate used ip adress > 1 per day (day by day for a whole contest time ) and will compare if other user_id from the same ip didn't voted same day which is illegal too. Sorry for bad English.

Can you help me?

vid | vpic | user_id | vip | vdate | vsum

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, you have to use a SELECT query to count those rows where the user id is equals to the one's who trying to vote and the the ip address stored in row equals to the actual voter's ip address and the day of the date is less than today's or the month is less than the actual month or the year less than the actual year.

If the count returns back more than 0 it means the client can't submit his vote.